# Replace values with assign in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA', 
                               '123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE', 
                               '67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG',
                               np.nan]})
df
    Address
0   234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA
1   123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE
2   67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG
3   NaN
```

And I want to create a new column. In this case firstly I replace NaN with `--`, and the rest of the non NaN is 'Yes'. So I tried this:

```py
df_mod = (
    df
    .assign(
        verify = lambda x: '--' if x['Address'].isna() else 'Yes'
    )
)
```

I want to do it in a chain using sign because there are more columns in the dataset. But I get this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

This is the expected result

```py
df
    Address                              Verify
0   234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA   Yes
1   123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE        Yes
2   67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG           Yes
3   NaN                                  --
```

Please, any help to do it using 'assign' will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

if you want use boolean masking, use boolean masking function(`mask`, `where`, `np.where` and so on) instead `if`.

```
import numpy as np
out = df.assign(verify=np.where(df['Address'].isna(), '--','Yes'))
```

out

```
                              Address verify
0  234 JALAN ST KULAR LUMPUR MALAYSIA    Yes
1       123 BUILDING STREET SINGAPORE    Yes
2          67 CANNING VALE, HONG KONG    Yes
3                                 NaN     --
```

If you must use the assign function with a lambda function to perform Boolean masking, you can use the following code:

```
out = df.assign(verify=lambda x: np.where(x['Address'].isna(), '--','Yes'))
```

---

The code you provided is not valid. chk following code:

```
'--' if df['Address'].isna() else 'Yes'
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Related: refer to the following post to know error:

[truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet of code:

```
df_mod = (
    df
    .assign(
        verify = lambda x: x['Address'].apply(lambda addr: '--' if pd.isna(addr) else 'Yes')
    )
)
```

I've tested it on my local machine and it works as expected.